# Получение сообщений из частного Telegram-канала, где бот является участником (не администратором!)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Суть задачи:
Получать для дальнейшей обработки сообщения из закрытого канала, в котором бот не является администратором.
Вопрос:
Можно ли реализовать это, используя Bot API, или необходимо использовать полноценный Telegram API?
В FAQ по ботам на офф. сайте указано следущее:

All bots, regardless of settings, will receive:
...
All messages from channels where they are a member.

Я пытался использовать пакет Telegram.Bot, но не нашел примеров и документации по своей задаче.

Comment: Не знаю как устроен телеграмм, но логично предположить, что если канал закрыт, если у бота нет доступа к нему, то он не может что либо от туда взять, не?

Comment: Аккаунт, с которого создавался бот, состоит в канале, т.е. бот по идее должен иметь доступ к сообщениям канала. Спасибо, тоже интересный момент для уточнения.

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38566728/12888024)

Comment: Режим приватности выключен, да. Но я не могу понять, как реализовать обращение к каналу через используемый пакет. Документация по нему не закончена, и примеров нет. Потому и сомнения в том, что это возможно.

Comment: не думаю что бот должен иметь доступ к сообщениям из твоего аккаунта в принципе. Будь то открытые каналы или закрытые. По твоей логике так должно быть, по моей - нет. :)

Comment: Для начала найди хотя бы возможность написать сообщение от имени твоего аккаунта - если такой возможности нет, то вряд ли будет и просматривание закрытых каналов твоего акка. А я уверен что такой возможности нет. Что бы была - нужно смотреть не в сторону написания бота, а в сторону написания кастомного телеграм-агента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что для чтения сообщений из каналов, которые не принадлежат аккаунту бота или где он не администратор, можно использовать только Telegram API (User API). Вопрос закрыт.